# Delete rows with specific string from a datable

Tags: r, string, delete-row

I have a data table consists of 3 columns and 1000+ rows generated from R. The first two columns are strings and the last characters are similar in some columns(they denote cell type). I want to filter out information only from non-similar rows.

```
AAA.aa BBB.aa 0.9
AAA.aa BBB.bb 0.8
CCC.cc DDD.cc 0.7
CCC.cc BBB.bb 0.8
```

I want my output as:

```
AAA.aa BBB.bb 0.8
CCC.cc BBB.bb 0.8
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried? generally, you should post what you have tried and what did not work as needed. ///// also, what is the criteria for "non-similar" in your sample data?

Comment: Do you mean this? `subset(df, !mapply(grepl, sub(".+\\.", "", V1), V2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep only the part of the string that you want to compare and remove using `!=`

```
subset(df, sub('.*\\.', '', V1) != sub('.*\\.', '', V2))

#      V1     V2  V3
#2 AAA.aa BBB.bb 0.8
#4 CCC.cc BBB.bb 0.8
```

This can also be used in `dplyr::filter`

```
dplyr::filter(df, sub('.*\\.', '', V1) != sub('.*\\.', '', V2))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("AAA.aa", "AAA.aa", "CCC.cc", "CCC.cc"), 
V2 = c("BBB.aa", "BBB.bb", "DDD.cc", "BBB.bb"), V3 = c(0.9, 
0.8, 0.7, 0.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
    filter <- apply(Z,MARGIN = 1,function(x){
                                             paste(x,collapse = "")
                                             }) %>% duplicated

    Z[filter,]
```